# Is there a Galois extension over Q with degree 11?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I tried to use Q($\xi_{23}$),  Q($\xi_{89}$), in the first one, it is Galois with degree 22, it does have a fixed field of degree of 11 as the group of order 22(namely G)has a 2-sylow group, but as this sylow group is not normal in G, thus the fixed field is not Galois over Q. The similar thing happned in the second example. so I wonder if such a field exits.

Comment: As $G$ is abelian, all of its subgroups are normal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pick any $n$, like $23$, such that $11$ divides $\phi(n)$ and let $\zeta\in\mathbb C$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity. Then the Galois group $G$ of $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$ over $\mathbb Q$ is isomorphic to the group of units of the ring $\mathbb Z_n$, which has order $\phi(n)$. Our choice of $n$ implies that $G$ has a order divisible $11$, and then $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of index $11$. The fixed field of $H$ in $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$ is a Galois extension of degree $11$ of $\mathbb Z$.

I am using here the fact that if $A$ is a finite abelian group whose order is divisible by a prime $p$, then $A$ has a subgroup of index $p$, which you can prove in many ways; you can find one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413470/number-of-subgroups-index-p-equals-number-of-subgroups-order-p).

Comment: One piece of information you seem to be leaving out is that the Galois extension of cyclotomic extensions are abelian. This is a very basic fact about them! You can find the proof in pretty much every field which deals with cyclotomic extensions.

Comment: In the case of $n=23$, you can actually write down the minimal polynomial for $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ by hand, though since it involves calculating the eleventh power of this binomial, the job is somewhat tiresome. You get a degree-eleven polynomial, and it’s easy enough to see that the splitting field is of degree $11$. Nothing fancy is required, though.