# Prove that number of subgroups of order p equals the number of subgroups of index p.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

My question is in relation to the answer on the following post by @Biao: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1975135

I've solved part a) myself, but I'm stuck on part b). I understand how to count the subgroups of order p and index p for the most part. However, I don't understand why we can assume A is elementary abelian. The Dummit and Foote book suggests this as a hint but I don't see how. Could someone clear this up for me?

Edit: Here's the problem.

> > Let $A$ be a finite abelian group and let $p$ be a prime. Let $A^{p} = \{a^{p}\mid a \in A\}$ and $A_{p} = \{x\mid x^{p} = 1\}$.
> >     a) Prove that $A/A^{p}$ is isomorphic to $A_{p}$, and
> >     b) prove that the number of subgroups of $A$ of order $p$ equals the number of subgroups of $A$ of index $p$.

Comment: What's part b)?

Comment: I've edited my question to include the actual question.

Answer (score 4):

Both $A_p$ and $A/A^p$ have exponent $p$, so, as they have the same
order, they are both isomorphic to $C_p^n$ for some $n$.

Each order $p$ subgroup of $A$ is contained in $A_p$, and there
are $(p^n-1)/(p-1)$ of these. Each index $p$ subgroup of $A$
corresponds to an index $p$ subgroup of $A/A^p$. These subgroups
are kernels of non-zero homomorphisms from $A/A^p$ to $C_p$
and there are $p^n-1$ of these homomorphisms. But two of these
homomorphisms have the same kernel iff they differ by a scalar
factor, so there are $(p^n-1)/(p-1)$ of these kernels.

Comment: Thank you. Could you clarify how each subgroup of A with index p corresponds to a subgroup of A/A^p with index p? I️ think that’s where my confusion is.

Comment: @gHem Every index $p$ subgroup of $A$ contains $A^p$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnkown +1 How do we know that there are $p^n-1$ of these homomorphisms?

Comment: I think it's because $n$ should be $k$ :-) @Pascal'sWager

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I mean, how do we know that the number of non-zero homomorphisms $(Z_p)^n \to Z_p$ is $p^n-1$?

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Well, there are $p^n$ homomorphisms from $(Z_p)^n\to Z_p$, but one of them is the trivial one, sending all elements to zero, so there are $p^n-1$ non-zero homomorphisms.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ok, I get it now. Another question: Why do two homomorphisms have the same kernel iff they differ by a common scalar factor? I see the backwards direction, but not the forward. Let's say $f$ is the nontrivial homomorphism defined by $f((x^{a_1},...,x^{a_n}))=x^{i_1a_1+...+i_na_n}$ and $g$ is the nontrivial homomorphism defined by $g((x^{a_1},...,x^{a_n}))=x^{j_1a_1+...+j_na_n}$. Assume $ker(f)=ker(g)$. How do we show that $(j_1,...,j_n)=c(i_1,...,i_n)$ for some $c$? (up to reduction mod p)

Comment: @Pascal'sWager I also have the same question. Do you figure it up now? If so, could you please explain it to me?