# Given the background, how to show any map onto a cyclic group of order $p$ is of this specific form?

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, p-groups

My question arised from an explanation to the proof of another problem. Here is the original problem, posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515246/prove-that-number-of-subgroups-of-order-p-equals-the-number-of-subgroups-of-inde):

> For a finite elementary abelian group, the number of subgroups of A of order p equals the number of subgroups of A of index p.

And the proof was also attached to the [previous link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515246/prove-that-number-of-subgroups-of-order-p-equals-the-number-of-subgroups-of-inde), where I quote here:

> Both $A^p$ and $A/A^p$ have exponent $p$, so, as they have the same order, they are both isomorphic to $C^n_p$ for some $n$.
> Each order $p$ subgroup of $A$ is contained in $A^p$, and there are $(p^n−1)/(p−1)$ of these. Each index $p$ subgroup of $A$ corresponds to an index $p$ subgroup of $A/A^p$. These subgroups are kernels of non-zero homomorphisms from $A/A^p$ to $C_p$ and there are $p^n−1$ of these homomorphisms. But two of these homomorphisms have the same kernel iff they differ by a scalar factor, so there are $(p^n−1)/(p−1)$ of these kernels.

What I don't understand is the argument

> two of these homomorphisms have the same kernel iff they differ by a scalar factor

I can see if these two homomorphisms differ by a scalar factor then they have the same kernel, but I cannot show the opposite direction. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you have a couple of misprints. "Both $\color{red}{A_{p}}$ and $A/A^{p}$, and "Each order $p$ subgroup of $A$ is contained in $\color{red}{A_{p}}$".

Comment: Then your problem is basic linear algebra. Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over a field $F$. Let $K$ be a subspace of $V$ of dimension $n-1$. Fix $v \in V \setminus K$. Then a linear map $f : V \to F$ with kernel $K$ is completely determined by its (non-zero) value on $v$. If $f_{a}(v) = a$ and $f_{b}(v) = b$ are two such maps, then...

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you for both your correction and your explanation. I forgot about the assumption that $K$ is of index $p$...