# The number of subgroups of order $p$ equals the number of subgroups of index $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> The number of subgroups of $A$ of order $p$ equals the number of subgroups of $A$ of index $p$ where $A$ is a finite abelian group and $p$ is a prime number.

Facts

1. $A/A^p\simeq A_p$.
2. The statement holds for elementary abelian group $(\Bbb Z/p)^n$.
3. $A_p$ is an elementary abelian group.

The question was already [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/413470/668308) but here's a proof I'm stuck on:

Let $A$ is a finite abelian group. If $P<A$ is a subgroup of order $p$ then $P<A_p\simeq A/A^p$. Hence the number of subgroup of $A$ of order $p$ equals the number of subgroup of $A/A^p$ whose index is $p$. Here, I need to show every subgroup of index $p$ in $A$ corresponds to a subgroup of index $p$ in $A/A^p$. Equivalently I need to show any group of index $p$ contains $A^p$. But I can't see the correspondence.

Could you help?

Comment: This will not help with your technical query, but I think the most insightful way of proving the result is to prove that every finite abelian group $A$ is isomorphic to its dual group ${\rm Hom}(A,{\mathbb C}^*)$ (which can be reduced to the cyclic case, since $A$ is a direct product of cyclic groups), and then prove that, under this isomorphism, subgroups of order $p$ in $A$ correspond to subgroups of index $p$ in the dual.

Comment: @DerekHolt Is the statement true btw? It seems people accept this as a trivial fact : If $B<A$ is an index $p$ subgroup then $[A/A^p,B/A^p]$ has index $p$ so $B$ corresponds to $B/A^p$. But $A^p$ need not to be contained in $B$.

Comment: If $B < A$ has index $p$ then $A / B \cong \mathbf{Z}/p$, so $(A/B)^p = 0$, so $A^p \leq B$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard We don't know if $B$ is a normal subgroup of $A$.

Comment: I thought the groups we are talking about were supposed to be abelian!

Comment: @DerekHolt Ahhhhh right right. Thanks!