# The number of index $p$ subgroup and order $p$ subgroup for elementary abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

In my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4236339/668308), fact 2 says that

> For elementary abelian group $A=(\Bbb Z/p)^n$, the number of subgroup of $A$ of order $p$ equals the number of subgroup of $A$ of index $p$.

Here's [the proof](http://math.byu.edu/%7Echilders/MATH571/HW16.pdf) (last page). But I can't understand the proof of this.

> First assume $A = (\Bbb Z/p)^n$. Then fixing any non-identity element $\alpha$ of $(\Bbb Z/p)^n$, $P =\langle\alpha\rangle$ will have order $p$, and this group can be described by $p-1$ distinct elements of $(\Bbb Z/p)^n$. Now consider the composition of maps $(\Bbb Z/p)^n\to(\Bbb Z/p)^n/P\to(\Bbb Z/p)^n$ where the first map is the quotient map and the second map is an injection. So the image of the composition will be a subgroup of $(\Bbb Z/p)^n$ with index $p$. Since there are $p-1$ ways to fix representatives of $(\Bbb Z/p)^n/P$ and inject them into $(\Bbb Z/p)^n$, there are the same number of subgroups of order and index $p$.

In the proof, what is $(\Bbb Z/p)^n/P\to (\Bbb Z/p)^n$? I wonder how the map is defined. Could you help? Or is there any other way to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duality between subgroups of order $p^i$ and subgroups of order $p^{n-i}$ is non-canonical. This means that there is no way to describe a bijection between the two sets that does not depend on choices, in this case a generating set for the group.

Let $g_1,\dots,g_n$ be $n$ elements of order $p$ that generate $A$. Then the elements of order $p$ are labelled by tuples $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, not all $a_i$ equal to $0$, where such a tuple corresponds to the element $$\sum_i a_ig_i.$$

If one requires subgroups of order $p$ rather than elements, one simply takes the tuples up to scalar multiples, or equivalently, taking those whose first non-zero entry of the tuple is equal to $1$.

For subgroups of order $p^{n-1}$, this is equivalent to kernels of maps onto a group of order $p$. Given a tuple $\mathbf a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, and a group element $g=\sum_i b_ig_i$, write
$$f_{\mathbf a}(g)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i.$$
The kernel of the map $f_{\mathbf a}$ is the set of group elements $g$ such that
$\sum a_ib_i=0$. As before, the kernel depends only on the tuple $\mathbf a$ up to scalar multiple.

Thus to each tuple up to scalar, we can associate both a subgroup of order $p$ and a subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$. But this bijection is entirely dependent on the choice of generating set for $A$.

Comment: Thanks but I wonder Dummit Foote requires this much difficulty. I hope there is a more easy way to prove it (or elementary).

Comment: @love_sodam You can just count. There are $(p^n-1)/(p-1)$ subgroups of order $p$. Then for subgroups of order $p^{n-1}$ you have to choose $n-1$ linearly independent elements of an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space. This is complicated, but reduces to the same expression.